# Scraping with NodeJS and Cheerio takes too much time

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

This is my first time working with NodeJS, and I want to **scrape** the content of a page based on a param I passed in the url.

```
const cheerio  = require('cheerio');
const https = require('https');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('Type station name ', (search) => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 4000; i++) {
        (async (url) => {
            const content = await getScript(url);
            const $ = cheerio.load(content);
            let stationName = $('div[class=here] span[class=txtbold]').text();
            if(stationName.toUpperCase().includes(search.toUpperCase())) {
                console.log(stationName + ": " + i);
            }
            
        })('https://cg06.tsi.cityway.fr/qrcode/?id=' + i);
    }
    rl.close();
});

const getScript = (url) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https.get(url, (resp) => {
            let data = '';

            resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });

            resp.on('end', () => {
                resolve(data);
            });

        }).on("error", (err) => {
            reject(err);
        });
    });
};
```

The problem is that I have 4000 iterations and this script takes too much time to be executed.

How can I solve this please?

Comment: How long is it currently taking for 4000 iterations?  And, what amount of time would you consider acceptable?  Have you timed how much of the time is in the `getScript()` and how much is in the `cheerio.load()`?  That would be the first thing to establish.

Comment: For starters, you could probably load 10-50 (depending upon the capabilities of the target server) `getScript()` operations in parallel since those are all asynchronous.  You don't want to do too many at once as that may overwhelm the target server, but you can certainly do more than one at a time.